# VSO/TFS Build - Get sources folder structure

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I am trying to set up continuous integration on our Development branch.

Below is our folder structure:

[image: VSO Source Control project structure]

From the "Get sources" build step logs, I can see that the files are syncing like this:

```
 Syncing repository: Root (TFVC)
 Getting C:\a\12a34ff5\Root;C7
 Getting C:\a\12a34ff5\Root\global.json;C18
 Getting C:\a\12a34ff5\Root\src;C16
 Getting C:\a\12a34ff5\Root\MyProject.sln;C29
 Getting C:\a\12a34ff5\Root\MyProject.vssscc;C7
 Getting C:\a\12a34ff5\Root\src\MyProject.Api;C16
 Getting C:\a\12a34ff5\Root\src\MyProject.Api\project.json;C18
 ...
```

**Why is it not establishing a project folder?**  For example, I would expect it to be using the following folder structure:

```
 Syncing repository: Root (TFVC)
 Getting C:\a\12a34ff5\Root\MyProject\Development;C7
 Getting C:\a\12a34ff5\Root\MyProject\Development\global.json;C18
 Getting C:\a\12a34ff5\Root\MyProject\Development\src;C16
 Getting C:\a\12a34ff5\Root\MyProject\Development\MyProject.sln;C29
 Getting C:\a\12a34ff5\Root\MyProject\Development\MyProject.vssscc;C7
 Getting C:\a\12a34ff5\Root\MyProject\Development\src\MyProject.Api;C16
 Getting C:\a\12a34ff5\Root\MyProject\Development\src\MyProject.Api\project.json;C18
 ...
```

The repository set up in the build definition:

[image: Repository set up in build definition]

The triggers set up in the build definition:

[image: Triggers set up in build definition]

Answer (score 0):

You never set the folder to get AS your development folder. Therefore the get is done from that folder, not including it.

It is working as i would expect and I don't see an issue.